$\nabla f=h\nabla g$ implies $f=F(g)$?
Suppose we have functions $f,g,h\colon \mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ that satisfies $\nabla f=h\cdot \nabla g$,  where $\cdot$ is the scalar productof $\mathbb R^n$. Here we assume both $\nabla f,\nabla g$ are continuous. Can we prove that $f=F\circ g$ for some $F\colon U\to\mathbb R $? Here $U$ is a wdomain that contains $\operatorname{Im} g=g(\mathbb R^n)$.
It seems that the question for harmonic functions makes this question suitable.

I was trying the $1$-dimension case, where the equation comes to be $f'=h\cdot g'$. In the case where $g'\ne0$, applying the chain rule, we have $F'=h\circ g^{-1}$ and $F$ is determined up to a constant, and we can apply $f(0)=F(g(0))$ to find the constant. But what can we say about the case $g'$ change signs?

Try $f(x)=x^3$ and $g(x)=x^2$. There is no smooth (here, $C^2$) $F$. You indeed need $\nabla g$ nowhere zero.
See my answer here for more details.
